# Android Toast Won't Disappear

Tags: android

I show the toast, it doesn't disappear, even after the app is closed. How do I fix?

```
@Override
public void onClipStoreLoadedClipsNotification(ClipStoreLoadedClipsNotification notif) 
{
    final ClipStoreLoadedClipsNotification notification = notif;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Dialogs.DismissAll();
            list.onRefreshComplete();
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loadclipstext);
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loadclipsprogress);

            if (notification.moreClipsAvailable)
            {
                text.setText(context.getString(R.string.loading_clips));
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                text.setText(context.getString(R.string.no_clips));
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast.makeText(SugarLoafContext.playbackTabContext, "No clips found.", duration).show();
            }

            SugarLoafContext.currentCamera = notification.camera;
            clipList = notification.clips;

            refreshListView();
            readyToLoadMoreClips = true;
            if (!firstClipsLoaded)
                firstClipsLoaded = true;
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: set duration like this int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only explanation is that your `Toast` is called in a loop. You should track the `toast .show()` and see if it is not called an infinite times.

An other visual way would be to do this

```
 Toast.makeText(SugarLoafContext.playbackTabContext, "No clips found.", duration).show();
 Toast.makeText(SugarLoafContext.playbackTabContext, "Do you understand now?", duration).show();
```

I am sure you will see both toast alternatively during a looong time...

Answer (score 48):

Is it running inside a `IntentService`???

If it is so, the problem is that the Intent Services in Android run in a different thread than the main one, so the Toast is shown in a different thread than the main one, after the time to show is finished, the Android system is unable to find where is the Toast, so it can´t remove it.

I had the same problem, and now, i recommend everyone NOT to show `Toast` inside a `IntentService`, instead try to run one commom Service, or to open an Activity, or try something different if it is completely necessary to show the Toast.

The fact that the Toast doesn´t dissapear when you close the App is that the `IntentService` is still running, and you have to reboot the system or to uninstall the App for the Intent Service to be close.

Comment: It was not quite a problem to me, I was so excited to see something running on background :-)

Comment: For me also facing some problem, Same I am also using IntentService. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Launch an Activity, and let the Activity to be the one which launches the Toast. I know it is hard, but we have to understand the IntentService doesn't work on the UI Thread, so we have to launch an Activity (with the NEW_TASK flag, and let the Activity to launch the Toast). If you want, you can launch the Activity as invisible for the user not to see anything strange. Otherwise you can also check at the Snackbar element: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your device has no network connection, and your app does a license check and shows a Toast of results. One of my apps had this problem, as I was displaying a Toast when checking the app was licensed. Without a network connection the Toast telling the user that a license retry was to be done remained, and when I connected the Toast was removed, because the license check could work.